# Errors while building DPDK 17.02 and 16.11 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, dpdk

I'm trying to build DPDK 16.11.1 and 17.02.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit with kernel version 4.13.0 running as VirtualBox guest on a Windows 7 host:

```
wwa@ssa:~/dpdk-stable-16.11.1$ uname -a
Linux osboxes 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The DPDK configuration is `x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc`:

```
wwa@ssa:~/dpdk-stable-16.11.1$ make config T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc CC=gcc
Configuration done
```

While building DPDK I get the following compilation errors: `error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_enable_msix’`. Here is the full output:

```
wwa@ssa:~/dpdk-stable-16.11.1$ make CC=gcc
== Build lib
== Build lib/librte_compat
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_compat.h
== Build lib/librte_eal
== Build lib/librte_eal/common
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_atomic.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_byteorder.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_cycles.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_prefetch.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_spinlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_memcpy.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_cpuflags.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/generic/rte_rwlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_branch_prediction.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_common.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_debug.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_eal.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_errno.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_launch.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_lcore.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_log.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_memory.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_memzone.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_per_lcore.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_random.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_tailq.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_interrupts.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_alarm.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_string_fns.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_version.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_eal_memconfig.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_malloc_heap.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_hexdump.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_devargs.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_dev.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_vdev.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci_dev_feature_defs.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_pci_dev_features.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_malloc.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_keepalive.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_time.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_rwlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_memcpy.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_cycles.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_spinlock.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_atomic_32.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_vect.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_prefetch.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_byteorder_32.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_atomic_64.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_rtm.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_cpuflags.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_byteorder_64.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_atomic.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/rte_byteorder.h
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal
  CC eal.o
  CC eal_hugepage_info.o
  CC eal_memory.o
  CC eal_thread.o
  CC eal_log.o
  CC eal_vfio.o
  CC eal_vfio_mp_sync.o
  CC eal_pci.o
  CC eal_pci_uio.o
  CC eal_pci_vfio.o
  CC eal_debug.o
  CC eal_lcore.o
  CC eal_timer.o
  CC eal_interrupts.o
  CC eal_alarm.o
  CC eal_common_lcore.o
  CC eal_common_timer.o
  CC eal_common_memzone.o
  CC eal_common_log.o
  CC eal_common_launch.o
  CC eal_common_vdev.o
  CC eal_common_pci.o
  CC eal_common_pci_uio.o
  CC eal_common_memory.o
  CC eal_common_tailqs.o
  CC eal_common_errno.o
  CC eal_common_cpuflags.o
  CC eal_common_string_fns.o
  CC eal_common_hexdump.o
  CC eal_common_devargs.o
  CC eal_common_dev.o
  CC eal_common_options.o
  CC eal_common_thread.o
  CC eal_common_proc.o
  CC rte_malloc.o
  CC malloc_elem.o
  CC malloc_heap.o
  CC rte_keepalive.o
  CC rte_cpuflags.o
  CC rte_spinlock.o
  AR librte_eal.a
  SYMLINK-FILE include/exec-env/rte_interrupts.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/exec-env/rte_kni_common.h
  SYMLINK-FILE include/exec-env/rte_dom0_common.h
  INSTALL-LIB librte_eal.a
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio
  AR      /home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.o
/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.c: In function ‘igbuio_pci_probe’:
/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.c:383:7: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_enable_msix’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   if (pci_enable_msix(dev, &msix_entry, 1) == 0) {
       ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic/scripts/Makefile.build:315: recipe for target '/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.o' failed
make[8]: *** [/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic/Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio' failed
make[7]: *** [_module_/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio] Error 2
Makefile:145: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[6]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/mk/rte.module.mk:79: recipe for target 'igb_uio.ko' failed
make[5]: *** [igb_uio.ko] Error 2
/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/mk/rte.subdir.mk:61: recipe for target 'igb_uio' failed
make[4]: *** [igb_uio] Error 2
/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/mk/rte.subdir.mk:61: recipe for target 'linuxapp' failed
make[3]: *** [linuxapp] Error 2
/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/mk/rte.subdir.mk:61: recipe for target 'librte_eal' failed
make[2]: *** [librte_eal] Error 2
/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/mk/rte.sdkbuild.mk:78: recipe for target 'lib' failed
make[1]: *** [lib] Error 2
/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/mk/rte.sdkroot.mk:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone has an idea why this breaks?
I have the same errors on both 16.11.1 and 17.02.1

Answer (score 0):

I see there's already a [fix](http://dpdk.org/dev/patchwork/patch/24076/) for that in newer releases of DPDK. I guess you have a few options:

- apply [the patch](http://dpdk.org/dev/patchwork/patch/24076/raw/) on your local DPDK code
- use a newer DPDK version
- use a Linux kernel older than 4.8

Edit: Applying the patch is not enough for DPDK 16.11.

If it's not an option to change DPDK version or move to an older kernel then you can also change the following code to call `pci_enable_msix_range` instead of `pci_enable_msix` in a similar way as done by the [dpdk patch](http://dpdk.org/dev/patchwork/patch/24076/raw/):

```
lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.c:

igbuio_pci_probe(struct pci_dev *dev, const struct pci_device_id *id)
{
    struct rte_uio_pci_dev *udev;
    struct msix_entry msix_entry;
    int err;

    [...]

    switch (igbuio_intr_mode_preferred) {
    case RTE_INTR_MODE_MSIX:
        /* Only 1 msi-x vector needed */
        msix_entry.entry = 0;
        if (pci_enable_msix(dev, &msix_entry, 1) == 0) {
            dev_dbg(&dev->dev, "using MSI-X");
            udev->info.irq = msix_entry.vector;
            udev->mode = RTE_INTR_MODE_MSIX;
            break;
        }
        /* fall back to INTX */
    [...]
```

Comment: The patch doesn't seem to solve all errors. Build still fails at: `/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.c: In function ‘igbuio_pci_probe’:
/home/osboxes/dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/igb_uio/igb_uio.c:383:7: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_enable_msix’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   if (pci_enable_msix(dev, &msix_entry, 1) == 0) {`

Comment: Please see the updated answer for applying the patch on dpdk 16.11

Comment: Thanks! Could you please paste the exact code to change? I tried but didn't succeed. Also, there is another error after this error is resolve: `dpdk-stable-16.11.1/build/build/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/kni/kni_net.c:124:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: For the `signal_pending` function the included header is wrong. You could apply the [patch for that](http://dpdk.org/dev/patchwork/patch/22037/). As I was saying initially, instead of patching the DPDK code it might be easier just to use a newer version of DPDK or a kernel older than 4.8.